# Using sequences in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm experimenting with sequences and ***handle*** widge, I'm using two test models to make it work

**Country**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models,fields,api
class t_country(models.Model):
        _name           =   "t_country"
        _rec_name       =   "description"
        _order          =   "description"

        description     =   fields.Char(string="description",required=True)
        states          =   fields.One2many('t_states','country_id',string="states")
```

**States**

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models,fields,api
class t_states(models.Model):
        _name           =   "t_states"
        _rec_name       =   "description"
        _order          =   "sequence"

        description     =   fields.Char(string="description",required=True)
        country_id      =   fields.Many2one('t_country',readonly=True,  string="country")
        sequence        =   fields.Integer(readonly=True,string="sequenece")
```

And I've been added the following line to my view

```
<field name="sequence" widget="handle" string="sequence"/>
```

But when I move the different records on the model their sequence numbers are not ordered as they have to.

The widget needs to be used with a function to change the sequence id's correctly?

EDIT

Added a image of a test screen
[image: I tried removing the readonly arg from my sequence butstill have the same result.]

*I tried removing the readonly arg from my sequence butstill have the same result. The only way to get the correct sequence with my code its moving a item to the first position to the list, then the rest of the sequence get calculated in order*

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence is in readonly, You cannot modify the value of the sequence.

Comment: I tried with readonly and without the argument and the result it's the same, I'll add a screenshoot on the main post